# Poner borde a una contendor

Tags: html, css

Tengo un contendor que he reducido y me gustaría ponerle borde a la parte que he reducido.

Ahora mismo el contenedor tiene el siguiente código:

```
.container2 {
    max-width: 100%; /*establecemos el ancho máximo del contenido*/
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}
```

Cual es el problema que si pongo border me lo hace fuera de los límites que he marcado y yo quiero que el borde lo haga en el padding-botom 50....

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Es decir he creado un contendor que he llenado de texto, pero ese contenedor en vez de empezar en el margen izquiero y derecho por defecto he hecho que se reduzca para que sea más centrado.

Saludos y mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es por el Box Model de CSS, puedes documentarte aquí: [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

La siguiente imagen muestra el orden en el que se aplican los espacios a la caja. Como se puede ver el padding es un espacio entre el borde y el contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso lo que deseas es agregar un borde que estaría en la zona del contenido así que ahí puedes agregar un div que cubra el 100% del área de contenido y ahí aplicar un borde.

```css
.principal {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
}


.container2 {
    max-width: 100%; /*establecemos el ancho máximo del contenido*/
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 1px;
    --background-color: blue;
}

.interno{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   background-color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<div class="principal">


  <div class="container2">
      <div class="interno">
        contenido
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: mil gracias, con el ejemplo lo he visto muchisimo más claro, ya he visto el tema de los 3 contenedores y como aplicarlo. Me has salvado la vida!